# MVC 5 storing dataSet so that I can retrieve it when calling an AJAX method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, dataset

Hey all I am new to the world of MVC so here is my question:

I have a dataset that has 2 (making it 3 total) other datasets merged into it. I am needing to use that information **later on in a call I do via AJAX** on that page.

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Switchboard/personData',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { reqID: 234 },
        success: function (response) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

As you see I am calling **personData** method in my controller via AJAX.

When the page loads I populate the dataset like so within my controller:

```
command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM .....", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 1);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(ds1, "theTrip");
allData.Merge(ds1);

command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM .....", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 1);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(ds2, "theMain");
allData.Merge(ds2);

command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM .....", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 1);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(ds3, "theEvents");
allData.Merge(ds3);
```

The **allData** is defined **globally** like:

```
DataSet allData = new DataSet();
```

And that does just fine and loads the needed data in the **allData** dataset.

However, when I click a button that calls the ajax method and it goes to that method that looks like this in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string personData(Int32 reqID)
{
    DataSet _ds1 = new DataSet();
        
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Admin FROM ....",con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(_ds1, "theLeads");

    allData.Merge(_ds1);

    _ds1.Clear();
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT categoryID FROM ....", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(_ds1, "theGroups");

    allData.Merge(_ds1);

    _ds1.Clear();
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ....", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(_ds1, "theTypes");

    allData.Merge(_ds1);

    _ds1.Clear();
    _ds1.Dispose();
    command.Dispose();
    con.Close();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allData, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

And again, it works but it no longer has my other data within it. It only has

> theLeads
>
> theGroups
>
> theTypes

instead of what I am needing it to be:

> theTrip
>
> theMain
>
> theEvents
>
> theLeads
>
> theGroups
>
> theTypes

The **theTrip**, **theMain** and **theEvents** were all populated when the page loaded up (as you can see with the code I posted) but it does not seem to save it when calling a method from that same page via ajax?

How can I accomplish what I am needing it to do?

Comment: You could cache it by using `Session`

Comment: @shoe how would that look? I didn't think that a session could hold a dataset?

Comment: `Session["allData"] = allData`. How much are you putting into it?

Comment: I have 3 tables within the dataset. I do not think I can merge those into a dataset from a session.

Comment: Then pass the `reqID` into your function and get the data from those tables again

Answer (score 1):

Your approch will not work as your application is a web application and you are making AJAX call. We applications are stateless so everytime you make a request to your service "allData" is initialized again with having no data from the previous state.

So in "personData" method you need to populate the older data again before you add new data to "allData".

Thanks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya